# Memory management when using macruby and Objective-C

Tags: ruby, cocoa

i have a `macruby` application that leaks *gigs* of memory. Ruby is for the logic stuff and accesses some Objective-C classes of mine, to access functions like Accessibility-API and making some screenshots and process them via CIImage.

**Having ruby and Objective-C code, which one handles the memory?**

As far as i know, ruby collects its garbage automatically but for Obj.-C I have to use some `NSAutoreleasePool`. But where should i `release` the pool? My ruby code needs to process the returned values.

In my project settings i has garbage collection enabled (`-fobjc-gc-only`).

Here is some code:

```
+ (CGSize) getSizeAttribute: (AXUIElementRef)element attribute:(CFStringRef) attribute {
  AXValueRef temp;  
  CGSize point;
  AXError resultCode;
  resultCode = AXUIElementCopyAttributeValue( element, attribute, (CFTypeRef *)&temp );
  AXValueGetValue(temp, kAXValueCGSizeType, &point);
  return point;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In your code,

```
resultCode = AXUIElementCopyAttributeValue( element, attribute, (CFTypeRef *)&temp );
```

temp is never released.

You should add:

```
CFMakeCollectable(temp)
```

MacRuby apps run in GC mode by default but your CF/Obj-C memory management can be a bit tricky (outside of MacRuby), check Apple's documentation available on their dev site.